# VBA copying rows only till a hidden row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to copy and paste data from one sheet to another after filtering

```
For j = 1 To 4
     
     ## Open both workbooks first:
     Set x = Workbooks.Open(path & "KFRs\" & sourceFileName)
     x.Activate
     Sheets("GL Data").Activate
     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
              
     
     Set y = Workbooks.Open(path & "KFRs\" & fileNames(j))
     
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:P" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=strNames(j)

     'Now, copy what you want from x:
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
     y.Sheets("GL Data").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
    Next j
```

When I see the destination file where it's supposed to be pasted, I see only rows till a hidden row is seen. For example, if first 4 rows are consecutive and after that there are a few hidden rows, it will copy only the first 4 rows. I need all the visible rows to be copied and pasted.

Comment: strange, code works for me, at least after having the same range in both sheets (you have A1:P and A1:L)

Answer (score 1):

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is breaking returning a Range of visible cell blocks called Areas.  The original code is only pasting the first Area.

`Range.PasteSpecial` only pastes visible cells.  By removing the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, all the visible rows will be pasted.

> ```
>  x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:L" & lr).Copy
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried removing the part you mentioned. But I see the same result as before.

Comment: @AdnanTamimi you need to clear the filter the data before finding the last row.  `Range.End()` returns the last visible row.